# VBA: Code to move a sheet that was just created to the furthest to the right of all tabs in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know a way in VBA to immediately move a tab that was just created to the furthest spot to the right of the entire workbook.  The way my code works right now is it places the tab to the furthest to the left (which is the default). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub AddSheet()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim strName As String: strName = CStr(MaxSheetNumber(wb) + 1)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
With ws
    .Name = strName
End With

'Line of code here that would immediately move the new tab "ws" to the furthest right position of all tabs in the workbook

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the `After` parameter:

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 ActiveSheet.Move _
 After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```